# if statement compare inputbox to cell.value

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Botão34_Clique()
Dim x As String
Dim z As Integer

InputBox "FIND PRODUCT", "TYPE" = x
For z = 2 To 143
     If Range("B" & z).Value = x Then
        MsgBox Range("B" & z)
    End If
Next z
End Sub
```

Hi guys,
I don't understand why the above code is not working.
The user's input will be compared with an existing product list.
When the input is equal to an existing product, the msgbox should indicate the cell in which it is present.
Unfortunately, I don't understand why the statement Range("B" & z).Value = x doesn't work...

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't your problem `InputBox "FIND PRODUCT", "TYPE" = x`, not `If Range("B" & z).Value = x Then`?

Comment: Change that to `x = InputBox("FIND PRODUCT", "TYPE")`

Comment: I updated my code to `x = InputBox("FIND PRODUCT", "TYPE")` but the code doesn't work, no msgbox appears

Answer (score 1):

You don't write the result of the `InputBox` into the variable `x`.
What you do is to call the `InputBox` with 2 parameters.

The first parameter (*"FIND PRODUCT"*) is the text that is shown in the input box as label.

The second parameter is used as form caption. You pass the expression `"TYPE" = x` as second parameter, and VBA will happily compare the string *"TYPE"* with the content of the variable `x`, resulting in either `True` or (most likely) `False`. So if you carefully look at the input box window, you will see the string *"False"* as caption.

Now the user enters something into the box and presses the "OK"-button. The entered value is returned, but you don't assign it to anything and the value is send to the big Computer Nirvana.

What you want is to assign the value to `x`. The correct syntax for this is

```
x = InputBox("FIND PRODUCT", "TYPE")
```

Note that in VBA, you have to put parenthesis around the list of parameters  when you are calling a function and use the return value.

Comment: I updated my code to `x = InputBox("FIND PRODUCT", "TYPE")` but the code doesn't work, no msgbox appears after IF statement

Comment: There are a lot of possible reasons: • You are not working with the correct sheet • The data doesn't contain the *exact* string, eg it has leading or trailing blanks. • Different data types... Best is to limit the loop (eg if you expect the value in row 80, let the loop run from 79 to 81) and check with the debugger content of `x` vs. content of the cell.

Comment: I debug the code with x between 2 and 4 and with the input equal to the string in cell B4, but the value of the input string is not recognized as being equal to the string in the cell

Comment: Then it's different - even if it looks the same. What are you looking for, strings or numbers?

Comment: @PedroSilva Note that the comparison is case-sensitive. Could this be the issue?

Comment: @FunThomas Strings

Comment: @Domenic How can I check if the string introduced in the  inputbox is equal to the string in the cell´s list

Comment: @PedroSilva If case-sensitivity is the issue, try `If LCase(Range("B" & Z).Value) = LCase(x) Then
`

Comment: Also try `trim()` to remove leading and trailing blanks

Comment: @Domenic  thanks for the support, but with these changes in the code the problem remains.......

Comment: @FunThomas that could be useful for future problems

Comment: @PedroSilva Just in case both case-sensitivity and leading/trailing spaces are the problem, try `If LCase(Trim(Range("B" & Z).Value)) = LCase(x) Then`

Comment: Put the statement `Debug.Print "[" & x & "]  [" & Range("B" & z) & "]"` before your If-statement and check what's printed in the immediate window

Comment: @Domenic fantastic, that works perfectly, very thankful !!!

Comment: @FunThomas I didn´t know that resource, I´m grateful for the information, thank you!

Comment: @PedroSilva Glad we can help, cheers!